# ASP.Net Web Form dynamic base page or hook page load event from out side

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have huge number of aspx pages. i want to fire a common function from all aspx page page load event but for that i need to add the function call in all page load event of all aspx page. so i am looking for a easy trick bu which i can make possible a function call from all page load event of all aspx page in my site.

so is it possible to hook page load event from out side or can we create a base page which will attached with all aspx page dynamically.

but i do not mean by base page like

```
public partial class MyBase: System.Web.UI.Page
{

}

public partial class index : MyBase
{

}
```

the above way i do not want to solve the problem bacuse if i follow the above way then i have to edit all aspx pages in my site. i need any easy trick to hook page load event.

please guide me.

### EDIT

```
private void OnBeforeExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var app = (HttpApplication) sender;
        HttpContext context = app.Context;
        //insert your code here
         string sVal = BBAreman.CountryCookie.GetCookieValue();
         if (sVal.Trim() == "")
         {
            Response.RedirectPermanent("~/country.aspx?ShowCountry=true", true);
         }
}
```

i am checking cookie value...if found none then redirect to country.aspx. so when country.aspx load then again code try to redirect to country.aspx.....infinite loop start.
guide me how to code for this situation. thanks

Comment: Have you considered an HttpModule? Your question doesn't go into enough detail to know if the Page needs to know about the function or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need an [HttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms227673(v=vs.100).aspx).

Your code then should look something like

```
public class MyModule : IHttpModule 
{

    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        //hook your onload event here. There are other events that could be more suitable
        app.PreRequestHandlerExecute += OnBeforeExecute;
    }

    private void OnBeforeExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var app = (HttpApplication) sender;
        HttpContext context = app.Context;
        //insert your code here
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

Do not forget to check out the module registration section in the link above.

Note: there are many more events that are fired in the asp.net pipeline, have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473(v=vs.85).aspx) for a list of them. Maybe there is a more suitable event depending on what you need to do

EDIT

Since you posted the code, there are a few things you can do to improve this

1. DO NOT use RedirectPermanent in this case. A simple 302 Redirect is fine.  Browsers tend to cache permanent redirects 'cause you know, they're permanent, no need to check again. So you end up with 2 infinite loops: a) the browser has cached the 301 and always redirects you to the country ballot screen, b) your code always redirects to the ballot screen anyway
2. You should insert some logic that checks whether the page is the ballot screen, and if so avoid redirection. Maybe something like this:

   ```
   HttpContext context = app.Context;
   if(context.Request.RawUrl.IndexOf("country.aspx",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
   {
       return;
   }
   //rest of your code here
   ```

An aside: you should have been able to figure this one out yourself. I took a look at your profile page, there are almost a thousand questions you asked, and the ones I sampled should be easy to research and resolve yourself. Something tells me you delegate all your programming to SO people. You get a -1 from me.

Comment: when OnBeforeExecute will fire? does it fire before pageload of any aspx page? plzz guide. thanks

Comment: @Thomas: If you visit this page [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473(v=vs.85).aspx) and scroll towards the middle, you can see in the table a list of events fired during the lifetime of a request. OnBeforeExecute above is hooked to PreRequestHandlerExecute, so it will fire before your pages' PageLoad event. MSDN states: [Occurs just before ASP.NET begins executing an event handler (for example, a page or an XML Web service).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.prerequesthandlerexecute(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: your solution was not good. OnBeforeExecute() is invoking again & again and a infinite loop start.

Comment: Each event is fired once per request, except from a few of them that may [seem to fire twice for extensionless urls](http://forums.asp.net/t/1868629.aspx). However the infinite loop thing should not be happening, unless of course there is an infinite loop somewhere in your code. You should check your access logs (iis logs) to see if there's something fishy going on with requests in your application. You may also want to paste the module's code here to take a look.